# Pandas count values by condition for row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table:

```
x A B C D
A 1 
B 1 1 1 1  
C 1   1
D
```

And I want to know a count of 1 in every row.
Expected result: `{ A: 1, B: 4, C: 2, D: 0 }`

I tried something `df[A][df[A]==1]`, but it give me same result but by column.
I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Try this: `df.eq(1).sum(1).to_dict()`

Comment: No. It give me result by column again.

Comment: what is the output of `print(df.dtypes)`?

Comment: [dtype('int32') dtype('int32') dtype('int32') dtype('int32')]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DataFrame:

```
In [120]: df
Out[120]:
   A  B  C  D
A  1  7  5  4
B  1  1  1  1
C  1  0  1  9
D  0  2  3  4
```

Solution:

```
In [121]: df.eq(1).sum(axis=1).to_dict()
Out[121]: {'A': 1, 'B': 4, 'C': 2, 'D': 0}
```

Explanation:

```
In [123]: df.eq(1)
Out[123]:
       A      B      C      D
A   True  False  False  False
B   True   True   True   True
C   True  False   True  False
D  False  False  False  False

In [124]: df.eq(1).sum(axis=1)
Out[124]:
A    1
B    4
C    2
D    0
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Hm. I was wrong when I said that this expression gave me result by columnt, I checked and this exp really give me result by row. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the values in the dataframe were numbers (1 or 0), you could use sum by rows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1],[1,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0]],\
    index=['A','B','C','D'],\
    columns=['A','B','C','D'])

print(df.sum(axis = 1))

A    1
B    4
C    2
D    0
dtype: int64
```

If they are strings ('1' or '') you can use the same, only the *sum* operator concatenates them, and then you map them to their lengths.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['1','','',''],['1','1','1','1'],['1','','1',''],['','','','']],\
    index=['A','B','C','D'],\
    columns=['A','B','C','D'])

print(df.sum(axis = 1).str.len())

A    1
B    4
C    2
D    0
dtype: int64
```